# Create new Git repo at GitHub through restful API?

Tags: ruby, git, github

Is it possible to create a new Git Repo at GitHub through restful API and not manually through their site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see the [Repositories API](http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html) page.  You do a post to `repos/create` with at least a `name` parameter.

Comment: But I don't get that part. Don't I have to specify my user account information first?

Comment: @ajsie: You obviously need to authenticate first.

Comment: @Matthew  the link is getting a 404 in github, searching for the new address.. will post that as soon as i get..

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Github gem](http://github.com/defunkt/github-gem) for example uses of the Github API; here's the implementation of the [`create` command](http://github.com/defunkt/github-gem/blob/master/lib/commands/commands.rb#L186).

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:
curl -u "USERNAME:PASS" -F 'name=REPONAME' http://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/create

from: http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html